# When should I transform variables?

Tags: regression, linear-model, logarithm

I am a bit confused when to use, and how to identify the need to use the following transformations: log, quadratic and inverse, in a linear model.

Usually the models I'm looking at have around 8-10 quantitative variables.

My main issue is that I'm not sure what to look out for. For e.g in log, is the shape of the distribution and skew/kurtosis values sufficient? So if the skew/kurtosis indicates a distribution closer to a normal distribution, then it makes sense to use log on the variable?

Comment: This is a big subject, about which entire books have been written.  The duplicate provides a brief introduction to part of it.  For more details and examples also see https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/35717/919, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4831, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10975, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11985, *etc.*

Comment: Thank you very much! @whuber